# Fonts so big in mobile <p> and other tags

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-size

my fonts in mobile is so bigger than desktop! (iphone 5c). I'm test EM font size and nothing... and others pages H2, h4... some diferents sizes in mobile but my css is same...
I used reset.css and i never can this problem...
sorry my english! rsrs

Example:

```
<h4 class="sub-titulo">texto</h4>
```

(http://visibilita.com.br/teste01/missao-visao-valores.php)

Comment: Post a relevant code sample here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use this css properties:

```
text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

The webkit browser adjusts the text of certaint tags to what it thinks is best. This can have the effect that you expenrience.

Keep the browser from adjusting the text by adding this to the style of your body:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your reset.css use `font-size:100%` property for your elements like `p, h1, h2` etc.
Try to replace it and declare your own properties. For example:

```
p {
    font-size:15px;
}

h2 {
    font-size:21px;
}
```